# Deleting multiple objects in core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a NSManagedObject subclass that has some deep relationships. The relationships affected here are as follows (for e.g.):

order.subOrders

suborder.items

So, an order has multiple suborders (to-many) and a suborder has multiple items (to-many).

Let's say my order has 3 suborders and each suborder has 3 items. I need to delete one item from each suborder at approximately the same time.

So, I've tried the following:

```
for(Item *item in itemsToBeDeleted) {
        [context deleteObject:item];
}
[context save:&error];
```

I then re-run the app and it seems that only 1 of the items has been deleted. So, I delete the 2 remaining items (using the same method) and re-run the app, but again only one has been deleted.

Can anyone maybe point me in the right direction at all?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you put only one `Item` object in `itemsToBeDeleted` collection. Could you post the code showing how that collection is populated please?

Comment: Thanks Michal. There are definitely the correct number of objects in the collection as I NSLog'd each iteration. Each object in the collection appears to be the correct object that needs deleting too....

Comment: Good to know that, but if you expect help I am afraid you must upload more code for analysis. I do not think there is something wrong with the code above.

Comment: Thanks Michal. The code is indeed a hell of a lot more complex than just that (although the deletion part itself is that simple). The problem solved itself when I started to use different code when iterating over these items. I can only assume I made an error in one of my methods when collecting the items to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the right panel of your core data model object, there are delete rules for your entities. If you set the delete rule of the topmost entitity to "cascade", the deletion will propagate down the relationship.

[image: Delete rule]